# Scroll bars in Facebook iframe app... again

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I'll do the same thing twice with two different results!!!
 
I set up a store here and it works fine
link to app: https://www.facebook.com/stlocarina/app_365351356883221

And the code to loose scroll bars:

```
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId : '365351356xxxxxx', //Your facebook APP here
      cookie : true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    });
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(91);
  }
</script>
```

After trying the same code here, I have scroll bars.

link to app in FB: https://www.facebook.com/AshevilleAleTrail/app_420678397982002

Here's the code I'm using (thats not quite working) to try and auto resize:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : '420678397xxxxxx', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//www.publicityresultshosting.com//channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

  };

 // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: '420678397xxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        FB_RequireFeatures(["CanvasUtil"], function(){ FB.XdComm.Server.init("xd_receiver.htm");
            FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent(); });
           FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(true,500);
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
   </script>
```

Any ideas on how to address this?

Comment: rtfm? (setAutoResize is deprecated and not used anymore) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the size, and after page load you can run the `setAutoGrow()` inside the callback.

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 950 });

FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading( function(response) {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
});
```